# PHP, use strtotime to subtract minutes from a date-time variable?

Tags: php, strtotime

I need to subtract 45 minutes from the date-time variable in PHP.

The code:

```
$thestime = '2012-07-27 20:40';
$datetime_from = date("Y-m-d h:i",strtotime("-45 minutes",strtotime($thestime)));
echo $datetime_from;
```

returns the result `2012-07-27 07:55`.

It should be `2012-07-27 19:55`, though. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should do:

```
$datetime_from = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("-45 minutes", strtotime($thestime)));
```

Having `H` instead of `h` means a 24-hour format is used, representing the hour with leading zeros: `00` through `23`.

You can read more on this in the [PHP date function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

---

There are also object oriented ways of doing this which are more fluent, like [`DateTime::sub`](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.sub.php):

```
$datetime_from = (new DateTime($thestime))->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('45 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

Or the even more expressive way offered by the [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library which extends PHP's built in `DateTime` class:

```
$datetime_from = (new Carbon($thestime))->subMinutes(45)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```