# strtotime minus hours and minutes

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I have this code:

```
<?php 
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 hours', (int)get_the_time('U'))); 
    echo $date; 
?>
```

as you can see the time is changed by subtracting 6 hours from the time, what I want to subtract the hours and also minutes so I tried this:

```
<?php 
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 hours', '-23 minutes', (int)get_the_time('U'))); 
    echo $date; 
?>
```

But isn't working, any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, use strtotime to subtract minutes from a date-time variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688829/php-use-strtotime-to-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-time-variable)

Comment: `strtotime` only accepts 2 arguments, not 3. Put the hours and minutes into the same string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function expecting only 2 parameters.

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

So you should try the following format:

```
$date = strtotime('-6 hours, -43 minutes', $time);
```

**Tested Code:**

```
<?php
$time = time();
$date = strtotime('-6 hours', $time);
echo date('d-m-y H:i', $time);
echo date('d-m-y H:i', $date);


$date = strtotime('-6 hours, -43 minutes', $time);
echo date('d-m-y H:i', $time);
echo date('d-m-y H:i', $date);
```

**Output:**

```
19-10-17 00:44
18-10-17 18:44

19-10-17 00:44
18-10-17 18:01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time=time();
$datetime_from = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("-43 minutes", strtotime("-6 hours",$time)));
```

Comment: Check out my answer.
Because less code is better ;)